# Регистрация через devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Имеем модель `User`, также стоит `Devise`. У юзера кроме стандартных полей, я добавил `first_name` и `last_name`. Эти поля сделал обязательными для заполнения пользователем. Вопрос, как сделать регистрацию новых пользователей через стандратную страницу девайса, не добавляя поля имя и фамилия? Как сделать возможность заполнить эти данные после регистрации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выполните `rails g devise:views`. Devise сгенерирует вьюшки в ваш проект, и после этого можете делать с ними всё что хотите.

UPD:

На [английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804591/rails-activerecord-validate-single-attribute) советуют действовать так, чтобы проверить только один атрибут на валидность:

В модели `User` написать метод:

```
def valid_attribute?(attribute_name)
  self.valid?
  self.errors[attribute_name].blank?
end
```

Затем в контроллере `UsersController`:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(email: user_params[:email], password: user_params[:password], password_confirmation: user_params[:password_confirmation])
  if @user.valid_attribute?(:email)
    @user.save(validate: false)
    redirect_to '<такой-то адрес>'
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: я немного другое спрашивал :) как регнуть юзера и не вводить first_name и last_name, хотя эти поля обязательноые

Comment: @АлександрИванов дополнил

Comment: в точку! спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так (в модели User):

```
validates :first_name, :last_name, presence: true, on: :update
```